# Задать заливку svg в css

Tags: css, html5, css3, svg

Всем доброго времени суток! Решил попробовать использовать svg-файлы в верстке, но столкнулся с проблемой - не задается цвет заливки. Пытаюсь прописать через fill, но тщетно.
Вот код css

```css
.icon {
  background: url("img/icons/book.svg");
  background-size: 15px 16px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 16px;
  fill: #ffb600;
}
```

вот svg

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="32" viewBox="0 0 30 32"><path d="M14 5h2v20h-2zM16 32h-2c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3h-11v-2h11c2.8 0 5 2.2 5 5zM16 32h-2c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5h11v2h-11c-1.7 0-3 1.3-3 3zM12 25h-12v-25h11c2.8 0 5 2.2 5 5h-2c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3h-9v21h10v2zM30 25h-12v-2h10v-21h-9c-1.7 0-3 1.3-3 3h-2c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5h11v25z"/></svg>
```

в итоге иконка заливается черным, хотя по идее должна быть желтой. 
Прошу помощи опытных. Спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот обсуждение этой проблемы на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367868/modify-svg-fill-color-when-being-served-as-background-image

Фактически, ответ такой: background-image не является частью DOM, поэтому манипулировать им нельзя. Поэтому путей решения два:

Не ставить svg на фон, а просто включить в документ: http://jsfiddle.net/pn640zLt/

```
<style>    
    .icon {
      fill: #ffb600;
    }
</style>
<div class="icon">
  <svg>...</svg>
</div>
```

Или же манипулировать содержимым собственно SVG на лету с помощью JS, примеры выше по ссылке.

Comment: премного благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

Класс icon надо задать path, a не svg и всё будет.

```
<path class="icon" d="M14 5h2v20h-2zM16 32h-2c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3h-11v-2h11c2.8 0 5 2.2 5 5zM16 32h-2c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5h11v2h-11c-1.7 0-3 1.3-3 3zM12 25h-12v-25h11c2.8 0 5 2.2 5 5h-2c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3h-9v21h10v2zM30 25h-12v-2h10v-21h-9c-1.7 0-3 1.3-3 3h-2c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5h11v25z"/></path>
```

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых случаях можно создать маску/негатив целевого SVG, а вот фон под этой маской уже менять в DOM  обычными методами.

Answer (score 0):

Используй

```
<path fill="currentColor" d=...>
```

как в fontawesome

у меня сработало