# Как менять цвет SVG иконки с помощью get параметров

Tags: svg

Добрый день. Появилась задача - создать svg иконку в которой с помощью get параметра будет меняться цвет.
Есть вот такой пример: https://github.trello.services/images/icon.svg?color=999. Где `999` это цвет в hex.

Стал смотреть [сюда](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/), но ничего для работы с get параметрами не нашел. 
Интересно как это делает github? Хранит svg не в файле, а генерирует при каждом запросе и отдает?

Comment: там же в исходнике, если посмотреть, xml-код меняется с разными значениями color: 2 строка, `<svg fill=...`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426890/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-svg-%D0%B2-css

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n это я вижу. Но не пойму как оно меняется. С помощью чего.

Comment: Получаете get-параметры из урл, ищите в них color и добавляете в svg атрибут fill="#+color". А на каком языке получать параметры - решать вам